# Функция memset_word делает пропуск между словами

Tags: c, указатели, память, memory

Пока писал учебную ОС, пришлось в качестве одной из функций стандартной библиотеки написать функцию `memset_word`. Проблема была тут же решена "в лоб":

```
    void memset_word(uint16_t* mem, uint16_t value, size_t count) {
        uint16_t* addr;
        for(addr = mem; addr < mem + count * sizeof(uint16_t);
                addr += sizeof(uint16_t)) {
            *addr = value;
        }
    }
```

Но у этой функции было обнаружено неприятное свойство: она записывает слова через одно. Другими словами, память была такая:

`00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00`,

а после вызова

```
    memset((uint16_t*) 0, 0xCDAB, 3)
```

стала такая:

`AB` `CD` `00` `00` `AB` `CD` `00` `00` `AB` `CD` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00`,

хотя должна была стать такой:

`AB` `CD` `AB` `CD` `AB` `CD` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00`.

В принципе, помогает замена `addr += sizeof(uint16_t)` на `addr++`, но я не понимаю: ведь указатели в C - настоящие адреса, так почему же для того, чтобы перейти к следующему слову, нужно прибавлять 1, а не размер слова? Или же ошибка кроется где-то в коде функции? Прошу объяснить мне это.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас эта функция

```
   void memset_word(uint16_t* mem, uint16_t value, size_t count) {
        uint16_t* addr;
        for(addr = mem; addr < mem + count * sizeof(uint16_t);
                addr += sizeof(uint16_t)) {
            *addr = value;
        }
    }
```

некорректная. В ней неправильно используется арифметика указателей.

Я думаю, вы имели в виду следующее

```
   void memset_word(uint16_t* mem, uint16_t value, size_t count) {
        for(uint16_t *addr = mem; addr != mem + count; ++addr )
            *addr = value;
        }
    }
```

Вы должны перейти к следующему объекту. Увеличение указателя на 1 увеличивает его адрес на `sizeof( uint16_t )`.

В этом состоит принцип работы оператора индексирования, когда вы пишите, например,

```
mem[1]
```

что эквивалентно выражению `*(mem + 1)` и в виду коммутативности операции сложения вы можете также записать

```
1[mem]
```

Comment: Поправьте, `mem[1]` эквивалентно `*(mem+1)`

Comment: @insolor Спасибо. Это я сделал опечатку, так как внимание больше было приковано к арифметике указателей, чем к их разыменованию.:)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал не так. Арифметика указателей верная, и Ваша функция работала бы правильно, если бы архитектура машины была 16-разрядная. В 32-разрядных машинах размер слова равен 4 байтам. При этом все числа (кроме char), размер которых меньше 4 байт, аппаратно выравниваются по 4-байтному слову. Другими словами, нельзя (не рекомендуется) разместить два 16-разрядных слова в одном 4-байтном аппаратном слове.

В случае, если вы запишете подряд два 16-разрядных слова, процессору придётся осуществлять больше операций, чтобы извлечь его из оперативной памяти и записать обратно. Нужно извлечь 4 байта (1 инструкция), далее в зависимости от того, младшее это слово или старшее (сравнение, условный переход - 2 инструкции) осуществляется наложение маски 0xFFFF0000 или 0x0000FFFF соответственно (2 инструкции). Если это старшее слово, то осуществляется сдвиг на 16 бит (1 инструкция). Все эти инструкции осуществляются аппаратно. Итого извлечение 16-разрядного полуслова из 32-разрядного слова тяжелее в 6 раз (приблизительно). Поэтому решите, под какую архитектуру вы пишете и какой размер слова вам нужен.

Comment: "Ваша функция работала бы правильно, если бы архитектура машины была 16-разрядная." - не работала бы. Размер uint16_t не зависит от архитектуры, и выравнивание тут ни при чем. Суть в том, что при увеличении указателя на 1 значение адреса увеличивается на размер типа данных, в данном случае на sizeof(uint16_t). При увеличении указателя на sizeof(uint16_t), значение адреса увеличивается на sizeof(uint16_t)*sizeof(uint16_t) == 4. Посмотрите этот пример: http://ideone.com/T2Qimb

Comment: И все же такие 16-bit системы [бывают](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra757/spra757.pdf)  -- `On theC2000  and C5000  DSP platforms, a char is 16 bits;`. Остается предположить, что uint16_t == short и тоже 16 bits, т.е. sizeof(short) == sizeof(char) **== 1 !!!*** (откровенно говоря, сомневаюсь, что автор ответа имел в виду именно эти DSP от TI)

Comment: @avp, можно предположить, что для таких систем uint16_t скорее всего будет определен через char.

Comment: Пожалуй да, я невнимательно прочитал код. Но совет оставить выравнивание 16-разрядных полуслов по 32-разрядным словам (то есть оставить пропущенные 2 байта) остается в силе.